# Split and transpose large column (4137 rows) into several rows of the same length the row (196 rows, 21 columns) in R

Tags: r, split, transpose

I have a problem with R.

I have created the following two tables.

Sheet 1: "long_strategic_return_event_window"

| Date | Relative_day | daily_return_acquirer | CUSIPID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011-03-14 | -10 | 0.00000000 | 00187E203280 |
| 2011-03-15 | -9 | 0.00000000 | 00187E203280 |
| 2011-03-16 | -8 | 0.02400000 | 00187E203280 |
| 2011-03-17 | -7 | -0.02343750 | 00187E203280 |
| .... | .... | .... | .... |
| .... | .... | .... | .... |
| 2011-04-07 | 8 | -0.03488372 | 00187E203280 |
| 2011-04-08 | 9 | -0.04953146 | 00187E203280 |
| 2011-04-11 | 10 | -0.00422535 | 00187E203280 |
| 2016-01-15 | -10 | -0.01362530 | 0028241001499 |
| 2016-01-19 | -9 | -0.00271337 | 0028241001499 |
| 2016-01-20 | -8 | -0.01162503 | 0028241001499 |
| 2016-01-21 | -7 | -0.01201201 | 0028241001499 |
| .... | .... | .... | .... |
| .... | .... | .... | .... |

Sheet 2: "strategic_realizedreturn"

| ROW NAME | cusip_acquirer | RR(-10) | RR(-9) | RR(-8) | RR(-7) | RR(-6) | RR(-5) | RR(-4) | RR(-3) | RR(-2) | RR(-1) | RR(0) | RR(1) | RR(2) | RR(3) | RR(4) | RR(5) | RR(6) | RR(7) | RR(8) | RR(9) | RR(10) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00187E203280 | 00187E203 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 0028241001499 | 002824100 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 00287Y1092353 | 00287Y109 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 00430U10332 | 00430U103 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| 004498101906 | 004498101 | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA | NA |

I am desperately trying to take the column of sheet1$daily_return_acquirer and transpose it in the correct row of sheet2 if the CUSIPID of Sheet 1 is equal to the row name of sheet 2.

Every CUSIPID on Sheet 1 has exactly 21 values of daily_return_acquirer, which fit into the 21 columns of sheet 2. Sheet1$Relative_day should be equal to the rows on sheet 2 so: -10 = RR(-10), -9 = RR(-9), ..., 10=RR(10)

I have created a minimal reproducible example for both sheets to make it more understandable. I hope you can help me!

```
Sheet 1: "long_strategic_return_event_window"

structure(list(Date = structure(c(15047, 15048, 15049, 15050, 
15051, 15054, 15055, 15056, 15057, 15058, 15061, 15062, 15063, 
15064, 15065, 15068, 15069, 15070, 15071, 15072, 15075, 16815, 
16819, 16820, 16821, 16822, 16825, 16826, 16827, 16828, 16829, 
16832, 16833, 16834, 16835, 16836, 16839, 16840, 16841, 16842, 
16843, 16847, 18057, 18058, 18059, 18060, 18061, 18064, 18065, 
18066, 18067, 18068, 18071, 18072, 18073, 18074, 18075, 18078, 
18079, 18080, 18082, 18085, 18086, 14687, 14690, 14691, 14692, 
14693, 14694, 14697, 14698, 14699, 14700, 14704, 14705, 14706, 
14707, 14708, 14711, 14712, 14713, 14714, 14715, 14718, 15957, 
15958, 15959, 15960, 15961, 15964, 15965, 15966, 15967, 15968, 
15971, 15972, 15973, 15974, 15975, 15978, 15979, 15980, 15981, 
15982, 15985), class = "Date"), relative_day = c(-10L, -9L, -8L, 
-7L, -6L, -5L, -4L, -3L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, -10L, -9L, -8L, -7L, -6L, -5L, -4L, -3L, -2L, 
-1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, -10L, -9L, 
-8L, -7L, -6L, -5L, -4L, -3L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, -10L, -9L, -8L, -7L, -6L, -5L, -4L, -3L, 
-2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, -10L, 
-9L, -8L, -7L, -6L, -5L, -4L, -3L, -2L, -1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), daily_return_acquirer = c(0, 0, 
0.0240000000000001, -0.0234375000000001, -0.00799999999999997, 
0.0161290322580645, 0.0857142857142857, -0.00584795321637427, 
0.125, 0.0261437908496731, -0.0140127388535031, -0.0116279069767442, 
0.0457516339869281, 0.01875, -0.049079754601227, 0.0129032258064516, 
0, -0.0140127388535031, -0.0348837209302326, -0.0495314591700134, 
-0.00422535211267597, -0.0136253041362531, -0.00271336951159347, 
-0.0116250309176354, -0.0120120120120121, 0.0139311043566364, 
-0.00924306769922569, 0.0126071608673727, 0.00771912350597615, 
-0.0929083271559179, 0.0310542086624898, 0.0158520475561427, 
-0.0148244473342003, 0.0036958817317846, -0.000263019463440429, 
-0.015785319652723, 0.00133654103180979, -0.012279765082755, 
0.0056756756756757, -0.0233808116097822, 0.0217391304347826, 
0.0231618637220576, -0.00619914761720269, 0.0158544509421702, 
0.00511705257771513, 0.00483645157184688, -0.00329322355921476, 
-0.00050832380226194, -0.00508582326764152, -0.00817891373801918, 
0.0094060043808788, 0.00561654327291291, -0.00418888042650417, 
-0.162523900573614, 0.0350076103500761, 0.0294117647058824, 0.0388571428571428, 
0.00935093509350944, 0.0113079019073569, 0.00983429880102371, 
-0.0262806830309498, -0.0242498972461981, 0.000280819994383544, 
0.00761035007610347, -0.00755287009063441, 0.004566210045662, 
-0.0212121212121212, -0.00928792569659437, 0.0046874999999999, 
-0.0171073094867806, -0.0348101265822786, 0.00983606557377057, 
0.0551948051948052, 0.0784615384615384, 0.00713266761768899, 
-0.00141643059490082, 0.00425531914893621, 0.00423728813559326, 
-0.0295358649789029, 0.0159420289855072, 0.00427960057061345, 
0.0198863636363636, -0.0027855153203342, 0.00139664804469271, 
0.00590511097536142, 0.00485829959514174, 0.0394842868654311, 
-0.00523255813953494, 0.00331190337034876, -0.00349514563106796, 
0.0134450506625097, 0.00596039223226307, -0.000382262996941956, 
0.011281070745698, 0.00226885989790126, 0.00811167704206753, 
0.00243263473053897, 0.00746686578308752, 0.00222345747637585, 
-0.00055463117027179, 0.0177580466148724, 0.00308978553253353, 
-0.0108715346983148, -0.00696098186481045, -0.0084855192768862
), CusipID = c("00187E203280", "00187E203280", "00187E203280", 
"00187E203280", "00187E203280", "00187E203280", "00187E203280", 
"00187E203280", "00187E203280", "00187E203280", "00187E203280", 
"00187E203280", "00187E203280", "00187E203280", "00187E203280", 
"00187E203280", "00187E203280", "00187E203280", "00187E203280", 
"00187E203280", "00187E203280", "0028241001499", "0028241001499", 
"0028241001499", "0028241001499", "0028241001499", "0028241001499", 
"0028241001499", "0028241001499", "0028241001499", "0028241001499", 
"0028241001499", "0028241001499", "0028241001499", "0028241001499", 
"0028241001499", "0028241001499", "0028241001499", "0028241001499", 
"0028241001499", "0028241001499", "0028241001499", "00287Y1092353", 
"00287Y1092353", "00287Y1092353", "00287Y1092353", "00287Y1092353", 
"00287Y1092353", "00287Y1092353", "00287Y1092353", "00287Y1092353", 
"00287Y1092353", "00287Y1092353", "00287Y1092353", "00287Y1092353", 
"00287Y1092353", "00287Y1092353", "00287Y1092353", "00287Y1092353", 
"00287Y1092353", "00287Y1092353", "00287Y1092353", "00287Y1092353", 
"00430U10332", "00430U10332", "00430U10332", "00430U10332", "00430U10332", 
"00430U10332", "00430U10332", "00430U10332", "00430U10332", "00430U10332", 
"00430U10332", "00430U10332", "00430U10332", "00430U10332", "00430U10332", 
"00430U10332", "00430U10332", "00430U10332", "00430U10332", "00430U10332", 
"00430U10332", "004498101906", "004498101906", "004498101906", 
"004498101906", "004498101906", "004498101906", "004498101906", 
"004498101906", "004498101906", "004498101906", "004498101906", 
"004498101906", "004498101906", "004498101906", "004498101906", 
"004498101906", "004498101906", "004498101906", "004498101906", 
"004498101906", "004498101906")), row.names = c(NA, -105L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000022eca291ef0>)

Sheet 2: "strategic_realizedreturn"

structure(list(cusip_acquirer = structure(1:5, .Label = c("00187E203", 
"002824100", "00287Y109", "00430U103", "004498101"), class = "factor"), 
    `RR(-10)` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `RR(-9)` = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `RR(-8)` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA"), `RR(-7)` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `RR(-6)` = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `RR(-5)` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA"), `RR(-4)` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `RR(-3)` = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `RR(-2)` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA"), `RR(-1)` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `RR(0)` = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `RR(1)` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA"), `RR(2)` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `RR(3)` = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `RR(4)` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA"), `RR(5)` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `RR(6)` = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `RR(7)` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA"), `RR(8)` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `RR(9)` = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `RR(10)` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA")), row.names = c("00187E203280", "0028241001499", "00287Y1092353", 
"00430U10332", "004498101906"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken (and I might be because you haven't filled in any of the values in the shell of your desired output), this is simply a `pivot_wider` combined with the addition of row names from the output shell:

```
long_strategic_return_event_window %>% 
  select(-Date) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from=relative_day, 
    names_prefix="RR", 
    values_from=daily_return_acquirer
  ) %>% 
  add_column(
    `ROW NAME`=rownames(strategic_realizedreturn), 
    .before=1
  )
```

Giving

```
# A tibble: 5 x 23
  `ROW NAME` CusipID  `RR-10`   `RR-9`   `RR-8`   `RR-7`   `RR-6`   `RR-5`   `RR-4`   `RR-3`   `RR-2`  `RR-1`      RR0      RR1      RR2      RR3      RR4      RR5     RR6      RR7
  <chr>      <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
1 00187E203… 00187E…  0        0        0.024   -0.0234  -0.00800  1.61e-2  0.0857  -0.00585  1.25e-1 0.0261  -0.0140  -0.0116   0.0458   1.88e-2 -0.0491   1.29e-2  0      -0.0140 
2 002824100… 002824… -0.0136  -0.00271 -0.0116  -0.0120   0.0139  -9.24e-3  0.0126   0.00772 -9.29e-2 0.0311   0.0159  -0.0148   0.00370 -2.63e-4 -0.0158   1.34e-3 -0.0123  0.00568
3 00287Y109… 00287Y… -0.00620  0.0159   0.00512  0.00484 -0.00329 -5.08e-4 -0.00509 -0.00818  9.41e-3 0.00562 -0.00419 -0.163    0.0350   2.94e-2  0.0389   9.35e-3  0.0113  0.00983
4 00430U103… 00430U…  0.00761 -0.00755  0.00457 -0.0212  -0.00929  4.69e-3 -0.0171  -0.0348   9.84e-3 0.0552   0.0785   0.00713 -0.00142  4.26e-3  0.00424 -2.95e-2  0.0159  0.00428
5 004498101… 004498…  0.00591  0.00486  0.0395  -0.00523  0.00331 -3.50e-3  0.0134   0.00596 -3.82e-4 0.0113   0.00227  0.00811  0.00243  7.47e-3  0.00222 -5.55e-4  0.0178  0.00309
# … with 3 more variables: RR8 <dbl>, RR9 <dbl>, RR10 <dbl>
```

Though, personally, I'd choose slightly more user friendly-column names for `R-10` etc...

Comment: Hello - This is exactly the desired output I am looking for. However, I would like to overwrite the "NAs" on sheet 2. Is that even possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Unless I'm misunderstaning you, simply asign the return value of my code to `strategic_realizedreturn`.  In other words, `strategic_realizedreturn <- long_strategic_return_event_window %>% ...`.